# IE10 browser - X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8 is not working

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jsp, browser, internet-explorer-8

My application is working fine IE8, When it comes to IE10 it is only working fine in computability view and with IE8 standards. To force the browser working in same mode I have used below code in my jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  --any code
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
  </head>
  --any code
</html>
```

But IE10 always used IE7 standards. Is there any thing wrong in above code? Please suggest.

Comment: You probably have local browser config settings that are overriding the meta tag. You could try setting the `X-UA-Compatible` flag via HTTP headers instead; I've heard that it takes precedence over user config when done that way, in cases where it may not always do so when set via a meta tag. (btw -- you really want to force IE8 mode?? In the name of sanity, *whyyyyyy????* ;-))

Comment: Thanks. Its working after adding to headers. As you suggested some configurations may be interrupting this.I preferred to force to IE8 because its working fine in that mode, not suitable for other standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it working through servelet filter which will always ensure working in same mode.

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (compatibilityMode != null) {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        res.addHeader("X-UA-Compatible", compatibilityMode);
    }
    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
}
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
  String compatibilityMode = config.getInitParameter("compatibilityMode");
}
```

Set computability mode through web.xml using below

```
<filter>
    ....
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compatibilityMode</param-name>
        <param-value>IE=8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```